# pandas calculate scores for each group based on multiple functions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
group_id    code    amount    date
   1        100      20       2017-10-01
   1        100      25       2017-10-02
   1        100      40       2017-10-03
   1        100      25       2017-10-03
   2        101      5        2017-11-01
   2        102      15       2017-10-15
   2        103      20       2017-11-05
```

I like to `groupby` `group_id` and then compute scores to each group based on the following features:

1. if `code` values are all the same in a group, score 0 and 10 otherwise;
2. if `amount` sum is > 100, score 20 and 0 otherwise;
3. `sort_values` by `date` in descending order and sum the differences between the dates, if the sum < 5, score 30, otherwise 0.

so the result `df` looks like,

```
group_id    code    amount    date          score
   1        100      20       2017-10-01     50
   1        100      25       2017-10-02     50
   1        100      40       2017-10-03     50
   1        100      25       2017-10-03     50
   2        101      5        2017-11-01     10
   2        102      15       2017-10-15     10
   2        103      20       2017-11-05     10
```

here are the functions that correspond to each feature above:

```
def amount_score(df, amount_col, thold=100):
    if df[amount_col].sum() > thold:
        return 20
    else:
        return 0

def col_uniq_score(df, col_name):
    if df[col_name].nunique() == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return 10

def date_diff_score(df, col_name):
    df.sort_values(by=[col_name], ascending=False, inplace=True)
    if df[col_name].diff().dropna().sum() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') < 5:
        return score + 30
    else:
        return score
```

I am wondering how to apply these functions to each group and calculate the sum of all the functions to give a `score`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`groupby.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for same size of `Series` as original `DataFrame` with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for `if-else` for `Series`:

```
grouped = df.sort_values('date', ascending=False).groupby('group_id', sort=False)

a = np.where(grouped['code'].transform('nunique') == 1, 0, 10)
print (a)
[10 10 10  0  0  0  0]

b = np.where(grouped['amount'].transform('sum') > 100, 20, 0)
print (b)
[ 0  0  0 20 20 20 20]

c = np.where(grouped['date'].transform(lambda x:x.diff().dropna().sum()).dt.days < 5, 30, 0)
print (c)
[30 30 30 30 30 30 30]

df['score'] =  a + b + c
print (df)

   group_id  code  amount       date  score
0         1   100      20 2017-10-01     40
1         1   100      25 2017-10-02     40
2         1   100      40 2017-10-03     40
3         1   100      25 2017-10-03     50
4         2   101       5 2017-11-01     50
5         2   102      15 2017-10-15     50
6         2   103      20 2017-11-05     50
```

Comment: You could make a starting point of `grouped = df.sort_values('date', ascending=False).groupby('group_id')` and then use `grouped` for most things...